# HTML smooth scrolling[without anchor animation]?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Would it be possible to create a smoother scrolling for a webpage?
For example MS Word 2013 has the kind of scrolling effect, 
I'm searching for.
Haven't found any other examples yet.
I've heard that you can do pretty much that kind of stuff with AJAX, so would it be possible with that?
I don't want a smooth scroll to anchor, but when you scroll down the page freely with your mouse wheel or the scroll bar. But I'm searching for a similar effect to this ''smooth scroll to anchor''.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by smooth scrolling?could you please elaborate?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex5/bookmarkscroll.htm#sectiona)?

Comment: As I said, I'm not looking for the ''anchor animation''. Though very similar to it. Take a look at the MS Word 2013 if you can, it has the effect I'm looking for. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WzTwfs_bbt8 at about 1:15 you can see it. Sorry for being so unclear, it's hard to explain.

Comment: Here's an almost perfect example, it's kinda too slow though. http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/

Comment: @user2907241 lemme get this straight.....what you want to acheiv is the same scroll motion effect in different browsers without any "anchor animation"? What you exatly want to say is that:-"can a user delay the scroll speed across various browsers in order to acheiv the effect which you showed in youtube video"?

Comment: @malcomX Yes, exactly. My english is kinda bad.

Comment: I remember a smooth scroll plugin that a developer incorporated into a web app of mine, it was nice, not very cross browser friendly though, maybe consider using smooth scrolling to anchor functionality with pretty arrows and well laid content instead of some flashy effect that will limit your device reach.

Comment: @BrianOgden you didn't get his question...... the answer which you posted earlier was related to anchor animation......

Comment: @brianodgen I'm already having the anchors animation. Read my question troughoutly. I don't know how useful it'd be, but it's worth of trying.

Comment: @user2907241 i have been trying to go through various resources but the answer to your question is :-"NO".You can change the color of the scrollbar,create your own custom scrollbars but you can't change the speed of the scroll bars.

Answer (score 1):

NiceScroll is what I was looking for.
It makes the scroll much smoother, as I wanted.
https://code.google.com/p/jquery-nicescroll/downloads/detail?name=jquery.nicescroll.350beta5.7z&can=2&q=

Comment: Hi NiceScroll does plays a good trick..... there are plenty of plugins available like that......hope it satisfies your requirements......

Comment: It's perfect for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

No. Scroll speed is determined by the browser (and usually directly by the settings on the computer/device). CSS and Javascript don't (or shouldn't) have any way to affect system settings.

You can try to fake it but the look and feel of the scroll bar would be compromised.

If and only if you capture the scroll events, then you would be able to adjust your content dynamically so that the portion you want is visible.

Flash might give you some liberty in acheiving your goal.

[EDIT]

**PLEASE DO NOTE:THIS IS WITHOUT ANCHOR TAG**
I tried to simulate a your query without any anchor tag.Although it's not perfectly answers to your question,it's still worth a shot:-

HTML:-

```
<div id="div1">asdf1</div>
<div id="div2">asdf2</div>
<div id="div3">asdf3</div>
<div id="div4">asdf4</div>
<div id="div5">asdf5</div>
<div id="div6">asdf6</div>
<div id="div7">asdf7</div>
<div id="div8">asdf8</div>
<div id="div9">asdf9</div>
<div id="div10">asdf10</div>
```

CSS:-

```
div {
height: 50px;
}
```

And finally add this to your jquery:-

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $("#div5").offset().top
   }, 5000);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it easily with JQuery**

Load JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
      $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

The above code will work perfect for the smooth scrolling

Comment: Hi .....if I am not mistaken,the question does states that the smooth scrolling should be enabled without any anchor animation.......please do check the question once......

Comment: Saw this code on CSS-Tricks. Can I ask, do you know why `html` **and** `body` are scrolled, and not only one of them?